# I have a list of list in C# and i want to bind the list in xaml using listview grouping

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Need help binding list of lists in xaml.

Have already tried to implement the same using Nested Listview but that's making my app crash when I scroll. I am guessing that's not a good idea.

Here is my Parent Model Class:

```
public class Parent
{

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Child> ChildList { get; set; }

}
```

Child Class:

```
public class Child
{
    public string ChildName{ get; set; }
 }
```

ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection< Parent > MyList = new ObservableCollection< Parent >();
```

In Mylist, I get a list of "Parent" objects, each containing the Id, Name and the 'ChildList' object which is also a list (multiple ChildList objects), containing ChildName

In my listview with Itemsource as "MyList", I want "Name" as the Header that contains the "ChildList" (Multiple "ChildName"s)

Something like:

```
Name1


-ChildName1

-ChildName2

-ChildName3

Name2


-ChildName1

-ChildName2
```

Can I achieve the same using listview grouping? If so, can someone please help me with the implementation as I am not able to group the data properly..

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#grouping

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to take another look at your design.  If I personally was trying to do something like what I understand you are trying to do, I would handle one of these two ways.

The first way, I would start off with a listview of parents.  I would then handle the clicked/tapped event (depending of what platform you are deving for) to open a second, smaller listview over the main page displaying the children of the parent that was clicked/tapped.  Clicking/tapping on anywhere on the screen other than the child listview would put it away.

The second way I can think of doing it is simply adding a parent to the  listview and then adding all of it's children.  Something list this:

```
void FillParentListView(List<Parent> parents)
{
    foreach(Parent p in parents)
    {
        listview.Items.Add(p);
        foreach(Child c in p.ChildList)
            listview.Items.Add(c);
    }
}
```

Downside with that second option is you would probably need to create different cell designs to make it easy to distinguish between a parent and child, and you would need to try cast every time you want to read info from the listview to see what's been selected.

Comment: ListView natively supports grouping

Comment: Well would you look at that.  I guess you learn something new every day.